# how to generate js file without webpackJsonp

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I want webpack to process js file (minify/uglify) but not format it as a module - so it would be just raw js file containing only the initial code (minified/uglified) without any webpackJsonp.
I need such a file to load it before webpack is loaded in a browser, to detect if custom font is loaded. If I use webpack module to do it then my bundle is loaded after font file is loaded.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Now html title of my question looks like "<title>javascript - how to generate js file without webpackJsonp - Stack Overflow</title>", what is totally wrong.  The same will be in search engines. Please get title of my question back.

Comment: welcome to the automatic advanced indexing options - this is how tags work. which proves my point - no tags in the title needed. I've removed the `javascript` tag, which should.fix your problem. and please, read the linked topic on meta - it really covers how the system works here. no offense implied.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair ok, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set your [target](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) to `node` in webpack.config.js (the default is `web`)

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node'
};
```

> In the example above, using node webpack will compile for usage in a
>   Node.js-like environment (uses Node.js require to load chunks and not
>   touch any built in modules like fs or path).

Alternatively, if this is not appropriate for your use, you can also just change the `libraryTarget` in the [output](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget) (assuming you are using CommonJS):

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
},
```

> libraryTarget: "commonjs" - The return value of your entry point will
>   be assigned to the exports object using the output.library value. As
>   the name implies, this is used in CommonJS environments.

Comment: target node doesn't seem to do anything for me. Using "webpack": "3.11.0".. was there any other webpack setting?

Answer (score 0):

You should have (depends on version) scripts() or babel() methods that only minify instead of js() that webpackfy also:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app') //this add a webpack module
    .scripts(['resources/js/scrips/raw.js', 'resources/js/scrips/raw2.js',], 'public/js/raws.js')//this add a minified js
    .babel(['resources/js/scrips/raw3.js', 'resources/js/scrips/raw4.js',], 'public/js/raws_retrocompatible.js')//this add a minified js, but using babel compiler
```