# How to build JS app with all the assets merged into single file component but not wrapped into webpack modules

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, webpack, components

Is it possible to build AngularJS/Angular/VueJS/*JS based app, with all the assets (fonts, images, styles, templates), merged into single file component/app, but not wrapped into any webpack module (like webpackJsonp) and without dependency on *.map.js files?

And by saying "not wrapped into webpackJsonp module" I mean the final output file, should be just transpiled/compiled pure ES5 code, inside IIFEs (Immediately invoked function expressions).

The code shouldnt be wrapped inside webpack methods, but should be standard, minified, uglified, ES5 *.min.js.
Just like the jQuery in the old days was, so something like that: `(function(t) {this._init(t)})()`.

Of course, inside should be also packed templates (html) and styles (both usually as a strings), also images and fonts (the last two's usually as a base64 code), but nothing wrapped inside webpackJsonp or any of it's methods.

I'm asking in context of my current work: I'm writing reusable account registration form component in VueJS 2.6.x, which I'd like to import and load on 3rd party websites.

But it must also work on IE11, so using Web Components is out of question, that's why I'm transpiling it with Babel.

Regarding the vendors part, I'm currently compiling vendors scripts as a vendor.[hash].js file, but knowing how to merge it with final output app.js during compilation, would be a plus.

Is it possible to achieve it and if not, at least something very close to that?

Comment: It seems that you oversimplify things. *assets (fonts, images, styles, templates)* - they aren't JS and thus it's not enough to just concatenate them into one file like you expected, they are supposed to be handled somehow to be loaded on the page. That's what Webpack does. If it has helper functions like webpackJsonp, it's probably because it need them to do its job. Sourcemap files are necessary for efficient debugging but you can delete them if you don't want to expose them. Try Rollup and Parcel if you're unhappy with Webpack output but it may not worth it in the end.

Comment: @EstusFlask I didn't said I'm unhappy. I just wonder if it's possible achieve what I've written about. I see in output code of some other app - Vuejs component built with webpack - that images, styles and templates are merged into code as strings (images as base64 code strings), but called by methods created by webpack.in the process of transpilation and compilation. I don't know if it's possible, but those methods could stay, even after stripping code out of webpack wrapper?

Comment: I don't remember how exactly things work in Webpack in this case but I expect this kind of optimization would make Webpack considerably less flexible. *are merged into code as strings* - this will pollute the output if the same thing is used more than 1 time. Modules allow to avoid this problem, this results in extra noise in the output. You can check Rollup for starters, its output is considerably cleaner.

Comment: I found good candidate for solution, [suggested by @Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46381748/13198379).

Comment: Does it suit you? It puts out redundant code from the output by assuming that you use Node or other environment that supports CommonJS natively. I won't expect it to work in a browser as is, not to mention that the output will still contain other junk besides webpackJsonp because Webpack works like it works.